# Installing a CRX file to Chrome

Tags: chromium, crx

I have been trying to install a CRX of a program that I have developed and I want to be able to install it by dragging and dropping it into chrome://extentions to make it easier for the people I am sharing it with. I do not want to load it or unpack it because I will most likely have to explain it to everyone.

I have searched multiple threads and forums researching how to do this, but have found none.

One app I used called moonlight allows you to drag and drop it to install it
(find it here https://github.com/moonlight-stream/moonlight-chrome/releases)
and I am wondering if there is any files I can replicate to make it possible for my program too.

On rockstar55's website (rockstar55.tk) on the school chromebook page, all the crx files he provides are able to be dragged and dropped into chrome://extentions